# Zend_Session_Exception thrown when APC extension is enabled?

Tags: php, zend-framework, apc

Does anyone have an idea why enabling the PHP APC extension (we're using PHP 5.3.26) would cause the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Session_Exception' with message 'Zend_Session::start() - /library/Zend/Loader.php(Line:146):
Error #8 include_once() [<a href='function.include-once'>function.include-once</a>]:
  Inserting [/library/Zend/Form/Element/Textarea.php] Array' in /library/Zend/Session.php:497
Stack trace:
  #0 /library/Zend/Session/Namespace.php(143): Zend_Session::start(true)
  #1 /library/Zend/Auth/Storage/Session.php(87): Zend_Session_Namespace->__construct('Zend_Auth')
  #2 /library/Zend/Auth.php(91): Zend_Auth_Storage_Session->__construct()
  #3 /library/Zend/Auth.php(141): Zend_Auth->getStorage()
  #4 /library/Zend/Controller/Plugin in /library/Zend/Session.php on line 497
```

It seems to be some sort of error involving session_start(), but I don't understand how APC would affect that.

Comment: Are you storing objects in the session?

Comment: Yes, i'm storing objects.

Comment: The issue probably relates to autoloading of the classes you're storing in the session. Make sure the ZF autoloader is being setup before you attempt to start the session.

Comment: The autoloader is set up already.  The code works on my local WAMP setup, but not on my VPS.

Comment: Do you have APC on your local setup? With the same settings? Same PHP version? Do you also have object data in your session on your local setup?